# From 3D velocity to coordinates

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics

I want to calculate the 3D position $T_x, T_y, T_z$ of an object with respect to a coordinate system if I have the mean velocity (norm) $v$ and its 3D rotation $(\omega, \phi, \kappa)$ with respect to the same coordinate system.
I want to use a naive motion model, as simple as possible.

So, I assume linear constant velocity and given the time I calculate $T=vt$ where $T$ is the 3D position, $v$ is the mean velocity and $t$ is the time. Then I use sphrerical coordinates to calculate the translation components 
$T_x=Tsin(\phi)cos(\theta)$
$T_y=Tsin(\phi)sin(\theta)$
$T_z=Tcos(\phi)$

Are the values $\phi$ and $\theta$ the same as the ones from $\omega,\phi,\kappa$?
Is it a correct approach, although simple? I don't want to use angular velocity etc.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Euler Angles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html).

Give a starting orientation versor $\hat{x}_{initial}$ and the rotation matrix $A$ you can compute the final orientation versor as $\hat{x}_{final} = A \cdot \hat{x}_{initial}$.

$v t $ times this vector will give you the final position, under your hypothesis.

Then you can compute the final position as $\vec{x}_{final} = v t (A \cdot \hat{x}_{initial})$.

Check the link to see how to compute A from $(\omega, \phi, \kappa)$.

Comment: Nice. I usually use the 3D Rotation matrix [R](http://truesculpt.googlecode.com/hg-history/38000e9dfece971460473d5788c235fbbe82f31b/Doc/rotation_matrix_to_euler.pdf), which I guess is the same with A you mentioned. The initial position is (0,0,0) as it is the start of the reference system. Can you provide me a link that explains the last formula  x=T(A*x)?

Comment: @Ellie I changed the post a little bit as it was misleading. Anyway, I guess you need to revise your notion of rotation matrix and its usage. It helps you describe the rotation of a body from one orientation to another. I understood your post as: "the final orientation of my body is given by $\hat{x}_{final} = A \cdot \hat{x}_{initial}$. Then let's suppose that it travelled with constant speed $v$ for a time $t$ along that direction. Where will it be now?" Did I understand correctly? If so, everything is stated correctly in my post.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. I have the 3D rotation matrix R with respect to the reference point, a mean velocity and time. I need to find the position. Everything is clear at your post, but I have one question. Since my initial position is (0,0,0), everything will be zero at the end?

Comment: Nope: let's say that $v$ is $1 \frac{m}{s}$, $t = 10 \, s$ and that your body initially is oriented towards the x axis: $\hat{x}_{initial} = (1,0,0)$. Let's say that $A$ rotate your body so that it looks towards the z axis $\hat{x}_{final} = A \hat{x}_{inital} = (0,0,1)$. Then you are supposing that it travelled $v t = 10 \, m$ in that direction. Then you'll find it in position $\vec{x}_{final} = 10 (0,0,1) = (0, 0, 10)$

Comment: Do you mean that $x_{initial}$ includes rotation? From your comment I understood that I shoud do $x_{initial}=(v,0,0)$, right?

Comment: Nope. You are mixing rotation and position. They are entirely different concepts. Your rotation matrix does not contain any information about the position. That comes from your hypothesis of uniform motion along the final direction. As in my example, given $\hat{x}_{initial}$, $A$, $v$ and $t$ you can calculate what you are asking. If any of these quantities is missing, you simply can't.

Comment: Understood. It just confused me yout comment about $x_{initial}=(1,0,0)$. I don't understand why it is like this, since my reference point is $(0,0,0)$

Comment: That's your reference POSITION. Not your starting ORIENTATION.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14968/discussion-between-lelesquiz-and-ellie).